# insertion function

Tags: c, insert

I have a homework problem where I have to:Write an insertion function that inserts an element at the first position in the list following an element storing a particular DATA item. I also have to use this function. I don't understand what the problem is asking. Can someone explain this problem to me in terms that are easier to understand?

```
#include "list.h"

LINK lookup(DATA c, LINK head)
{

if (head == NULL)
   return NULL;
else if ( c == head -> d)
        return head;
     else 
        return (lookup(c, head -> next));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking you to write a function that finds a specified item in the list, and then inserts the new item in the list after this position.

So given the list

```
List = {Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4}
```

Your function `List.Insert(Item2, Item5)` (for example) should result in

```
List = {Item1, Item2, Item5, Item3, Item4}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a linked list.  The list is composed of `LINK` structs (to be more precise, it appears the `LINK` type is typedef'd to be a pointer to the actual node structs.  We don't have the definition in front of us, but presumably each `LINK` struct holds a `DATA` struct as well as the usual linking pointer(s).

Your task is to take the head-of-the-list `LINK` and a `DATA` struct and search through the list until you find the first `LINK` that has a `DATA` identical to the one you're given.  Then, insert the new element into the list just before that `LINK`.

Answer (score 0):

You are asked to find `DATA c` in the linked list (the function `lookup( )` will do that for you), then insert a `DATA` item between `c` and the `DATA` item following `c`. If `c` is the last `DATA` item in the list, then you are to add your new `DATA` item as the final `DATA` item. If the list is empty, i.e. if `lookup( )` returns `NULL`, then your new `DATA` item should be stored as the one and only `DATA` item in the list.

Why not post the relevant part of `list.h` so we can understand what the linked list looks like?

It would also be a good idea to post the entire `lookup( )` function.

Comment: The only thing missing from the `lookup()` function is the closing '`}`'.